# Background-clip text from parent element

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a full-screen background that has some blocks with a black background on it. I would like to achieve that the text in those black blocks looks like it's cut out from the black box so you can see the background image.

Below is a simplified version of the HTML and CSS set-up:

```css
.background {
background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300); 
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;   
}

.blackbox {
background-color: black;
padding: 30px;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 100px;
margin-left: 400px;
}

.text {
font-size: 40px;   
font-weight: bold;
font-family: 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif;    
background-clip: text;    
-webkit-background-clip: text;
color: transparent;
background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300); 
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
   <div class="blackbox">
      <div class="text">TEXT</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

If I move the background image to the child text element, the clipping works but it doesn't match with the background-image on the parent element. I thought [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583947/css-background-clip-text-from-parent-element-background) had my answer but the child element doesn't have a background.

Comment: You may need to provide a more comprehensive version of your code, because your current code doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Hi @Crimp, I've added some more code to clarify, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be responsive. `mix-blend-mode` is what you're looking for:

Source (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_cutout_text.asp)

```css
.background {
background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/800px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png); 
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
height: 200px;
}

.text {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 5vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  line-height: 200px;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply; /* This makes the cutout text possible */
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="text">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @Crimp,

That works, but only if the black box is positioned in the left top corner so the background images of the parent and child element are perfectly aligned.

I changed my snippet to change the position of the black box. As you can see the clipping happens, but the background is not aligned, so it doesn't like like the text is cut out.

Comment: Great, that did the trick, thanks!